# Search for customers with 3 first payments, and have a specific combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I need is: I have to list all customer that have a payment plan (we charge every month of them) and have this combination: its first payment is done and the next 2 are still unpaid. The finance table have: 
 ID, PAYMENTPLANID, DATEDUE, AMOUNTEDUE, AMOUNTPAID

I know that row is paid when AMOUNTPAID > 0 and the DATEDUE indicates 
I need because I will cancel the payment plan in the end of the 3rd month if the customer only pays the first charge and stops for the next 2 month.

Is there a simpler way to identify this person that not involves 3 subselects (the only way I thought)?

Example:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ID, PAYMENTPLANID, DATEDUE,     AMOUNTEDUE, AMOUNTPAID |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1,  1,             2017-07-05,  10,         0          |
| 1,  1,             2017-06-05,  10,         0          |
| 1,  1,             2017-05-05,  10,         10         |
| 2,  5,             2017-07-05,  25,         25         |
| 2,  5,             2017-06-05,  25,         0          |
| 2,  5,             2017-05-05,  25,         25         |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The payment plan with ID 1 should be canceled this month since the person only paid the first payment.
The payment plan 5 should not be cancelled.

Comment: do you need planid as the output?

Comment: what do you expect your output to look like?

Comment: a list of PAYMENTPLANID so I can cancel them all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lead` with the optional 2nd argument to look 1 and 2 rows ahead and check for your conditions.

```
select * --distinct paymentplanid /*if only planid is needed as output*/
from (
select t.*
,lead(amountpaid,1) over(partition by paymentplanid order by datedue) as nxt_1
,lead(amountpaid,2) over(partition by paymentplanid order by datedue) as nxt_2
,lag(amountpaid) over(partition by paymentplanid order by datedue) as prev_1
from tbl t
) t
where amountpaid>0 and prev_1 is null and nxt_1=0 and nxt_2=0
```

Comment: If I understood well, this will not garante that the third charge is in this month. I must garante that this month is the 3rd charge of that paymentplan (it might be older payment plans charges, but it should be ignored)

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work ?

```
   select ID , PaymentplandID from
     (select ID , PaymentplandID , max(amount_paid ) over ( order by  ID , 
     PaymentplandID rows between current row and 1 following partion by Datedue  desc  ) 
  as amount  , 
 row_number() over ( order by select ID , PaymentplandID partion by Datedue  asc) as rn 
 from you_tble) t1 
  where t1.amount = 0 and rn = 3
```